# Why JavaScript behaves like that?

Tags: javascript, coercion

Let's look at those examples:

```
var a = 1;
var b = { toString:function() {return '1'} };
var c = 1;

a + b + c === "111" // true
```

---

It is pretty mind blowing. I know that JS interpreter performs ToPrimitive or ToString operations when we use + operator. But why is object b gets converted to a string when there is no hint PreferredType. Thus it is probably using ToString operation.

Another note: it is only gets converted to string if there is toString method exists on object, why? And if I call that method "toNumber", why it is not converted to number?

**Why JavaScript behaves like that?**

Comment: I would guess that because one of your variables is a string it assumes you're concatenating.

Comment: `b` is an object with a `.toString` method which you wrote, which returns '1' as a string. So `1 + '1' + 1 === '111'` because Javascript calls `b.toString()` presumably.

Comment: @Sam Orozco There is no string there, 2 numbers and object. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your function returns a string

Comment: When using `+` with an object, it will be coerced to be a string (Object has a toString method on its prototype). So even if you do not add one yourself it will automatically have a default one. Also there is no `toNumber` "magic" method like some other languages have, that is why naming your function that does not auto convert it to a number in operations

Comment: `it is only gets converted to string if there is toString method exists on object, why? ` That is partially true, but only because all objects have a toString. As long as `b` is not a number or value that can be coerced to a number, it will be converted to a string. If you haven't defined a `toString` function somewhere in the prototype, then `Object.prototype.toString` is used and the string will be `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: Indeed, you can see it here: `Object.create(null, {}) + Object.create(null, {})` (these are objects that are guaranteed not to have any methods, including `toString`) will give you `TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value`. An object needs either `toString` or `valueOf` in order to be able to participate in `+`.

Comment: `Why JavaScript behaves like that?` - because javascript language was created in 10 days

Comment: @Amadan, Very useful point!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But why is object b gets converted to a string when there is no hint PreferredType.

When no hint is passed, then the object's `valueOf` method will be called first. But since `b.valueOf()` doesn't return a primitive value (it returns the object itself by default), `b.toString()` will be called next.

See the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-toprimitive).

The conversion rule can be summarized as follows:

- If there is no hint or hint is `number`, call `valueOf` first.
- If hint is `string`, call `toString` first.
- If the return value is not is not a primitive value, call the other method.
- If the return value is still not a primitve, throw an error.

> it is only gets converted to string if there is toString method exists on object, why?

Not sure I understand this statement. Every object has a `toString` method. If you try to perform this operation on an object without a `toString` method (via `Object.create(null)`), an error is thrown.

> And if I call that method "toNumber", why it is not converted to number?

Because `toNumber` has no meaning in JavaScript. `toString` and `valueOf` are the two "magic" methods via which objects are converted to primitive:

```js
var n = 1;
var o = {
  toString() { return 'bar'; },
  valueOf() { return 2; }
};

console.log(n + o);
console.log(String(o));
```

If none of the methods return a primitive, you would get an error as well.

```js
    var n = 1;
    var o = {
      toString() { return this; },
    };

    console.log(n + o);
```

These two methods and their naming seems kind of arbitrary. From ES6 on, the preferred way to define a conversion function is to use the well-known `@@toPrimitive` symbol:

```js
var a = 1;
var b = { [Symbol.toPrimitive]: function() {return 1} };
var c = 1;

console.log(a + b + c);
```

`@@toPrimitive` is called before `valueOf` or `toString` are called.

> Why JavaScript behaves like that?

Because that's how it is defined in the specification. If you want to know the *rationale* behind that, you have to ask the people who made that decision.

Comment: I've got to admit: I hadn't ever encountered the toPrimitive Symbol before.

Comment: Looks like I gotta spend more time reading the docs. I haven't even realized about this `@@toPrimitive` until now..

Comment: @Felix Kling, I get it now. So object internal method toString was called and returned a string. When there is no internal toString method, JS uses Object.prototype.toString(). I can even add internal method valueOf to return whatever I want and make JS interpreter behave the way I want. Thanks.

Comment: @Hyphen: Yes, `valueOf` is basically what you expected `toNumber` to be.